# Node mongoose initialization exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting following exception for `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`

```
module.js:338
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\beerlocker\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mquery\lib\mquery.js:11:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

**P.S. I have the MongoDB installed and running.**

Comment: try:
rm -fr node_modules  &&
npm cache clear  &&
npm install

Answer (score 0):

I believe you didn't install the mongoose pacakge, do `npm install mongoose` to install the package